# Swift: How to avoid UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate crash?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

Here's an example code on how I decompressed a lz4-decompress data object:

```
extension Data {
    var calculatedResult: Data? {
        var result: Data?
        let size = 15_000_000
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: size)

        // Write data to buffer
        let resultLength = ... // calculate the length of the result data
        result = Data(bytes: buffer, count: read)
        buffer.deallocate()
        return result
    }
}
```

However I recently I'v been getting crashes: [image]

And the logs say "Could not allocate memory":
[image]

As I understand, this is caused by insufficient RAM space when creating the `buffer`. Is there anyway I can check whether the RAM is adequate before calling `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate()`?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: hi @hoang, did you find out whats the cause of the crash?